# Custom Title bar & Tabs

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar, android-titlebar

Is there any way to change the content of the title bar when it's in Tab(If it wasn't in tab I would have done it but tried couldn't find any solution). E.g. Suppose I have created a custom title bar with few buttons on it, and now I want to change the content of the title bar(Drawables, Title and the functionality).

It would be great if someone could tell me if i can implement Action bar in versions  below 3.0 ? I am creating this project in 2.1 (I'd like to create action bar from scratch).

or if there's any way beside inserting an image and placing buttons on it(This methodology would be good enough)?

Comment: do you want to changes the main activity title from child tab?

Comment: I want to change the title when it's inside the tab. E.g. I have a Tab which contains 5 tabs. Now for each of these 5 tabs i wanna show their own titles and different buttons on the title bar.

Comment: can you post images(using paint) for more clarification

Comment: Please have a glance http://cdn.loopinsight.com/wp-content/uploads/mzl.vlnrhszj.320x480-75.jpg I wanna implement like this like they do in Iphone. Here for the 'Home Tab' There's "Bands Found" button, I wanna change the content @ title bar for other tabs like suppose for Advanced tabs i'd like to add back button and another button there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're just looking to implement the ActionBar paradigm in pre-Honeycomb versions of Android, I suggest you look into using the [ActionBarSherlock library](http://actionbarsherlock.com/).

> The library will automatically use the native action bar when
>   available or will automatically wrap a custom implementation around
>   your layouts. This allows you to easily develop an application with an
>   action bar for every version of Android back through 1.6.

Comment: but the main problem is that i want to change the content of title bar when it is in tab.

Comment: One way you could do this is to have multiple ViewGroups (action bars) in your layout with different contents. You could set the visibility of all but one to "gone" (or "invisible"). Then, in your Activity or Fragment, you can toggle the visibility of each view depending on what content you want displayed. This would work well if there is a limited number of permutations that you want displayed. If you want the content to be truly dynamic, you might need to take a different solution. Could you give an example of what a user would have to do to see different content?

Answer (score 1):

twaddington and pjco's answers are correct, you need to use ActionBarSherlock if you want to be compatible with every SDK levels.

I want to add you can have a custom actionbar or a custom view for your actionbar tabs using the method [`actionbar.setCustomView(view)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setCustomView%28int%29) or [`tab.setCustomView(view)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.Tab.html#setCustomView%28android.view.View%29)

Anyway, play with ActionBarSherlock [demos](http://actionbarsherlock.com/samples.html), there are a few cool use cases.

Answer (score 0):

The other option worth looking at is ActionBarCompat, which I think comes with the SDK 14 api demos.  However, ActionBarSherlock seems to support many more features so that may be the better solution.

Comment: I wanna use it in 2.1 and i wanna build my own action bar without using any library. Would it be a good option to use the images and put the buttons on it?

Comment: ActionBarCompat is just an example class that works back to 1.6 (I think), ActionBarSherlok is a Library but more stable and with more features. Either way if you dont want to use a Library, just make a RelativeLayout or something.